# Which is the best npm module for Ping and traceroute?

Tags: node.js, ping, traceroute

I am bit confused which is the best npm module for ping and traceroute in node.js ?

My need is to store the output of the command only.

I am thinking about to use net-ping. Is there any other module you can suggest ?

Comment: IMO, `net-ping` outperforms all the other modules in terms of Popularity, Quality and Maintenance (You can see this legends) in the npmjs.com site's search results.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about use it. What about using execute command with exec module ?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried `exec` module, I normally prefer to use `node-cmd` module

Comment: Which is more preferable net-ping for tracert or node-cmd to execute direct command ?

Comment: `net-ping` allows us to ping and trace route to many hosts at once, hence it is better than other modules.

Comment: We also use net-ping widely and it is very stable. Using the exec module will probably end up with much smaller usage limits due to cpu and memory it'll require.